# Spring Request Mapping

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

this is what I am trying to achieve here. 
I have a login page which resides under
**WebContent/login.jsp**. This is the initial entry point to the app. Now I need to display an attribute name on this login page (which I get from the backend injecting myProperies.
I thought of routing this entry point through a controller in order to get the page Name but I am facing a problem where pageName attribute always return empty on JSP. Also the system out
never gets called. I think my controller is never getting callled? URL I am using is: http://localhost:8080/abc/login.html

```
package com.abc.xyz;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.abc.xyx.prop.MyProperties;

@Controller
public class PreLoginController {

    @Resource
    private MyProperties myProperties;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc/login.html",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMyLoginPage(ModelMap model){

        String pageName = myProperties.getMyPageName();
        model.addAttribute("page", pageName);

        System.out.println("my page name is: " + pageName);

        return "login";
    }

}
```

Comment: That code will not compile. `System` has a capital `S`, and the sysout line is missing a `;` (semicolon).

Comment: and what does your Spring context look like?

Comment: Thats just a typo. I am sorry. I replaced log.info with Syso. Code compiles fine.

Comment: @matt, Spring Context? Could you please elaborate...

Comment: the XML file(s) in which you wire up all your beans and configure Spring.

Comment: Well we are using autowiring and context component scan. Am I missing something with url I am using to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your @RequestMapping value should just be "/login" instead of "/abc/login.html", assuming your dispatcher servlet is looking for "html" and your context root is "abc"

Comment: Hi GriffeyDog, going to try your solution. I noticed in the logs that syso statement did print the results. Not sure when that happened as I was trying all sorts of combo's. What is the simplest way to find the context root of an app

Comment: Well, if you got to the JSP fine with http://localhost:8080/abc/login.jsp, then your context root is indeed /abc.  Generally, it's found in a server-specific file (i.e. on Weblogic it's in weblogic.xml)

Comment: It was my security config that was forcing the call back to non secured pages.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using spring security instead for this kind of matters? this will greatly reduce your effort and will allow you to concentrate on the actual webapp requirements

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html

Comment: Hi Marcelog, Thanks for the reply. I am using Spring Security in my app. Just that I wanted to test a pre login controller. Not sure why its not hitting.

Comment: could you post your web.xml and your application context xml file? also, you should use a logger instead of the system.out.println, try to log this way just to be sure your controller is not called

Comment: Hi  marcelog, On invoking the URL, I am getting this: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /abc/login.html has not been defined. Where am I missing the hook?

Comment: have you correctly setup and deployed your webapp in the app server? you need to deploy your webapp and have your app server started, configuring a context (like / or /myApp) so the server can know to which app it should redirect the request